# Как сделать метод приватным если в интерфейсе он публичный?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Point {
  make(): void;
}


class A implements Point {
    private make() {       <!-- Ясным образом выдает ошибку

    }
}
```

Возникает вопрос - как тогда заключать контракт класса с интерфейсом - так чтобы часть методов были приватными.

Получается что интерфейс не может описать защищенные свойства класса для наследования?

Comment: ознакомься с этим [declaration-merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) `class` `interface` `namespace`. [abstract-classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes). [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#implementing-an-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В интерфейсе всегда методы публичные будут. Можно абстрактный класс сделать, в нем можно сделать приватные методы, но с интерфейсом это не выйдет.

Comment: @webDev_, это как понимать?